# How to change IP Adress on Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I need to change my IP Address on a **webdriver** from Selenium in Python!
I tried the code above but now the project is **too slow** and not working anymore, probably because of timeout. Im also using **Google Colaboratory**!
Thanks!

```py
    sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=direct://132.163.0.10:8888')

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent="+user_agent)
    wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
```

I also tried this:

```py
    PROXY = "http://192.168.0.10:8888"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    }
    wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=chrome_options)
```

But it didn't work!

Answer (score -1):

Try using a proxy to change IP, I did with firefox, but you can change it to suit you best.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PROXY = "114.7.27.98:8080"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.dnsleaktest.com/")
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried this, but when triyng to access the page it takes too long to load, even when using expected_conditions! i already do the proxy thing on this line 'chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=direct://132.163.0.10:8888')'

Comment: btw, your code is givin the error - 'Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal'!

Comment: Remove try block, I put it there so it closes automatically in 10 seconds. It's taking too long because the traffic is going through proxy

Comment: @PwWolf The OP is using a Chrome web driver, **not** firefox.